# Active Admin - custom order/sorting with position in has_many to has_many polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, many-to-many, activeadmin, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic has_many to has_many association managed with Active Admin.
There are two different models BlogArticle and MagazineArticles that have many Authors through Authoring table.
The association is working correctly, but I have to create some kind of input in active admin that let the administrator specify the order of appearance of the Authors for any single Article.

So, the target is to obtain that any BlogArticle and Magazine Article has many authors with its custom order.

I can use an attribute of position put in authoring table, but how we can manage it in Active Admin?

In this moment my input field in MagazineArticle and BlogArticle is:

```
f.input :authors, 
   label: "Autori",
   as: :select, multiple: true,
   collection: Author.all.collect {|item| [item.full_name, item.id] }
end
```

this "select" puts the Authors ordered by updated_at of the author object (not of authoring object). This select comes from a gem called activeadmin-addons and it is perfect for us, but I can accept also another way to proceed.

models are:

```
class Authoring < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :author
    belongs_to :authorable, :polymorphic => true
    default_scope {order(position: :asc)}
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :authorings
    has_many :blog_articles, :through => :authorings,
        :source => :authorable,
        :source_type => "BlogArticle"
    has_many :magazine_articles, :through => :authorings,
        :source => :authorable,
        :source_type => "MagazineArticle"
end

class BlogArticle < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :authorings, :as => :authorable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :authors, :through => :authorings 
end

class MagazineArticle  < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :authorings, :as => :authorable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :authors, :through => :authorings
end
```

and its add correctly all the Authors I need, but clearly without any ordering.

How can I manage the position of the Authorings in Active Admin?

------- EDIT --------

I have tryied as suggested by [@Piers C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153279/piers-c) (thank you very much) to use [activeadmin_select_many](https://github.com/blocknotes/activeadmin_select_many) gem that seems to fit my needs, but it is now incompatible with my version of active_admin

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activeadmin":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activeadmin (= 2.6.1)

  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin

    activeadmin_select_many was resolved to 0.3.4, which depends on
      activeadmin (~> 1.0)
```

I tried "bundle update" but nothing to do - there is a big number of incompatibilities

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activeadmin":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin

    activeadmin_select_many was resolved to 0.3.4, which depends on
      activeadmin (~> 1.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.0.0)

    rails (~> 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.1.rc1, which depends on
      activemodel (= 6.0.1.rc1)

    web-console (>= 3.3.0) was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    friendly_id was resolved to 5.3.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)

    rails (~> 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.1.rc1, which depends on
      activerecord (= 6.0.1.rc1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    bullet was resolved to 6.1.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

    jbuilder (~> 2.7) was resolved to 2.10.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)

    rails (~> 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.1.rc1, which depends on
      activesupport (= 6.0.1.rc1)

    rename was resolved to 1.0.6, which depends on
      activesupport

    webpacker (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "listen":
  In Gemfile:
    listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)

    spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0) was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 6.0.0)

    rename was resolved to 1.0.6, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2, < 5.2)

    activeadmin_addons was resolved to 1.7.1, which depends on
      railties

    devise was resolved to 4.7.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.1.0)

    dotenv-rails was resolved to 2.7.5, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.1)

    rails (~> 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.1.rc1, which depends on
      railties (= 6.0.1.rc1)

    rails-i18n was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 6.0.0, < 7)

    sass-rails (~> 5) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 5.2.0)

    web-console (>= 3.3.0) was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 6.0.0)

    webpacker (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [activeadmin_select_many](https://github.com/blocknotes/activeadmin_select_many)?

Comment: Wow it seems fantastic, I never seen it but there is a very big issue: the gem is incompatible with my version active admin, i edit my question here below

Comment: I would reach out to Mattia and ask what he's doing these days, ask if he's willing to help update.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood of your question,

your desired outcome is whenever you call
`@blog_article.authors` or `@magazine_article.authors`, it should provide all the authors of that article in an order sorted by 'position' attribute of `Author`.

You can achieve this by adding, order in your `has_many :authors` associations in both the `BlogArticle` and `MagazineArticle` models.

Your association will then look like this:

```
has_many :authors, -> {order('authors.position')}, :through => :authorings
```

**OR**

You can define a default scope in your `Author` model, like this:

```
default_scope { order('position desc')}
```

Comment: Thank you Sohail,
but no, your solution is easy - I need a different order each article.
so the correct place where to put the position is the Authoring (and use the default scope on it).

But my question is a little bit complex, how can I manage the position of the authors in each single Article using active admin?